# Aged tequila on Pessach

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover, liquor-beer

I've noticed that the lists of aged (reposado and añejo) tequila approved for Pessach went from a fairly sizeable number in 5780 down to two in 5781. Someone I know, who is an executive in a nationally-recognised hechsher, only found these two after looking through at least five lists.

Neither of us had any idea what changed lema'aseh, so what factors would explain this drastic a change over the last year in Pessach-approved products ?

Comment: An offhand guess: the sizable observant  Mexican Jewish community is based in Mexico City, far from the algave groves and Tequila distilleries, and travel has been a bit complicated for the past year, to say the least

Comment: @Loewian, this list only gives blanco, which is un-aged, as a rule, so not particularly relevant to the question IMO